# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token due to span tag in return statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, kendo-ui

- When I click open first window link a popup opens.
- in that popup you will see a grid with two columns.
- in that first column i need to combine name and and icon.
- so i added span tag before a tag but its not working.
- can you guys tell me how to combine.
- providing code below.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

http://jsfiddle.net/6aa15duj/

```
 var csv = "a,b,c\n1,2,3\n";
 var data = new Blob([csv]);
 var a = $('<a/>', {
   class: 'sportsDataPlayer',
   download: 'download.csv',
   type: 'text/csv',
   href: URL.createObjectURL(data),
   html: ev.FileName
 });
 return "<span onclick=\"window.open('" + model.mobileVersion + "', 'popup', 'width=800,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no')\" class='" + skyCloudmageProfilePic + " displayInlineBlock " + kendotxtMenu + "'>
  </span>" + a[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: You have a literal newline character in your string, Javascript does not like multiline strings (without proper syntax, eg [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals))

Comment: @PatrickEvans can you update in my fiddle its so confusing :(

Comment: Take a look at the linked duplicate and use the syntax they suggest, or put all your span code on one line, eg put `</span>" + a[0].outerHTML;` on the same line as the rest of your code